# Storing user documents in S3 - design decisions

Tags: amazon-s3, architecture

I have an angular web app that will store CVs, cover letters, and user images. I'm trying to come up with a solution of buckets and folders that makes the most sense for my app.

For avatars, which are unique, I think it would be simple to:

- have a bucket named avatars
- name each avatar with the user-id of the user

For CVs, there are two kinds: one with full contact information, and another one edited to not reveal the contact information. For cover letters, those are also mostly unique. If I store only the most recent version, I could:

- have a bucket named Docs
- create a folder with the user-id of the user
- have items userid/cv-edited.doc, userid/cv-unedited.doc, userid/letter.doc

Is this a reasonable scheme? Are there any pitfalls?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a strong reason to separate the avatars from the user-id folders?  It sure seems simpler to keep a single path for all the data...  Then you can have permissions driven purely by the path.

Comment: I think you are right. I was thinking it might be easier though if I had to index through all the users avatars, for example, to display on some general area of the site. Some kind of GET * IN AVATARS, but perhaps I can write something like GET * IN DOCUMENTS WHERE NAME = avatar.* if I had to do that (I think S3 doesn't support SQL like querying, but just as an example)